# Convert a text box to dropdown box from Add view

Tags: cakephp

Can you help me figure this out please? I have 4 form elements on my add view (app\views\tickets\add.ctp) but the 'status' input is on a text box. I want that to be converted to drop down box populated with data from a field in a table called Status. How do I go about doing it?

```
echo $this->Form->input('problemno');
echo $this->Form->input('status');
echo $this->Form->input('description');
echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
```

Thanks,

Lyman

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force the type of input field, do not use the input() method, but use the method for the type you want.

To get a drop down list, you can use the select() method:

```
$options = array('status1' => 'status1', 'status2' => 'status2', ...);
$this->Form->select('status', $options);
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/view/1430/select

Answer (score 0):

If the model associated with your 'Status' table is related to you current model ('Ticket', presumably) with a hasMany,hasOne, or belongsTo (...as long as your 'Status' model shows up when you debug `$this->Ticket->read(null, <some_ticket_id>)`) you can do

```
echo $this->Form->input('StatusModel.field')
```

and cake will automagic that field to be whatever it needs to be.

You will have to search around for how to make cakePHP give you a dropdown selection based on database field.

Comment: I don't think I'm doing it correctly. What I'm going to do is get rid of that status table because it doesn't have any associations and what I'd really like is to populate a drop down box with 5 options so when I edit a ticket I could just select an option from the drop down box and push save. My question now would be, how can I add a drop down box with 5 default options from my Add view?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a correct way. It might be good, or you might find changing it later on to be a problem. But if you just want to create a dropdown with some options, here you go:

`echo $this->Form->input('status', array('options'=>array('status1'=>'status1','status2'=>'status2','status3'=>'status3')));`